# Is it ok to store React component in parent's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a component 'App', it stores 'Item' component in its state 'itemList' Like this:

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemList: [
        <Item />,
        <Item />,
        <Item />
     ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.itemList}
    );
  }
}

class Item extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="items">
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm new to ReactJS.
The code works, it successfully renders 3 div 'Item' component, but I wonder if this approach is legit, if not, how do I achieve this instead?

Comment: Whats the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but it would make more sense to store only the data you need, instead of the output of the Components

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemList: [
        "Item one",
        "Item two",
        "Item three",
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.itemList.map(item => <Item item={item} />)}
    );
  }
}

class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="items">
        {this.props.item}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

storing components in state isn't a good approach. Remove them from state and just render them in the `render` method

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <item>
         <item>
         <item>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

ps: You have to wrap your child components with a `div`. render should return a **single root DOM node**

Comment: I have a button that can add or remove item from itemList, it's up to users how many items are there, so I can't do it in this way.

Comment: @Reese: you can use @webdeb solution. (dont forget to add a wrapping `div` tho)

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't write in function `render()`.
State should be store value.